# Including query function to HTML from external file (using Dropbox to test locally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to add some simple jQuery through an external file. I would like the code to remain in the external .js file. I'm using [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) so I can test my site locally, and I am almost certain JavaScript works through this method, but I don't know about the jQuery library. I can't seem to get any feedback through trial and error. Here is the simple form of the code I'm attempting.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" ></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id='container'>
     <div class='menu'>
         <h2>Title of menu/h2>
     </div>
     <div class='panel'>
         <p>
            Some text here
         </p>
     </div>
</div>
</body
```

This is the entire .js file so far. Does this need to be defined as a function and then added into the HTML? Is it a scope issue?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow')
    })
})
```

Comment: The version of jQuery you're using is *really* old.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that got it working after I switched around the inclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your code ***after*** the jQuery inclusion..

So swap these lines

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" ></script>
```

That is because your code uses jQuery, so you need to load jQuery before you can use the `$`.

Answer (score 3):

You load your file before the library your file is using. Change the two `<script>` lines so that jQuery is loaded first:

Change

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" ></script>
```